# invoke void method

Tags: java, void

I need to invoke a void method before call another method.

I have this method

```
    public void shuffle() {
    various = new Random();

    currentCard = 0;
    currentTotal1 = 0;
    currentTotal2 = 0;

    for (int first = 0; first < deckOfCards.length; first++) {
        int second = various.nextInt(number_cards);

        Card temp = deckOfCards[first];
        deckOfCards[first] = deckOfCards[second];
        deckOfCards[second] = temp;
    }
}
```

And in another class I have:

```
public class GameRules {
final deck myDeckOfCards = new deck();
myDeckOfCards.shuffle(); //error here

// first
public ImageIcon GameRules1() {
    return myDeckOfCards.giveCardPlayer1().getImage();
}
```

The basic problem is that I need to do shuffle in the deck of cards before show a card. Without shuffle method the order of cards is sequential

Any idea? If I put the method inside `public ImageIcon GameRules1()` doesn't give error, but I need shuffle all cards before game, no before each give card method.

thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should place that call inside your constructor for the class:

```
public GameRules() {
    myDeckOfCards.shuffle();
}
```

The constructor is the place where you do initialization tasks for your objects.

Also, you really shouldn't have a method called `GameRules()` that returns an `ImageIcon`. You should rename that method `getImage` or something like that. Then, when you create a `GameRules` with the consturctor and call `getImage` on it, the deck will be shuffled.

Example:

```
GameRules gr = new GameRules(); // deck gets shuffled in constructor call
JLabel test2 = new JLabel(gr.getImage());
```

Check out the Java tutorials for a good [tutorial on writing constructors for your classes.](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html)

Comment: thanks for your answer. If i do what you suggest i still have the same problem. How i can call the method GameRules() whe i do something like that: final JLabel test2 = new JLabel(test00.GameRules1()); ?? that's the problem

Comment: @Fel, You really shouldn't have a `method` called `GameRules()` that returns an Image.  You should rename that method to `getImage` or something like that.  Then, when you create a GameRules with the consturctor and call`getImage` on it, the deck will be shuffled.  (See my edit.)

Comment: i solved the issue with {
  myDeckOfCards.shuffle(); 
}
 thanks

Comment: @Fel, you have many more issues that simply adding `{}` around some code will solve.  I'm glad you fixed your problem, but you should really consider some of my other advice.

Answer (score 5):

Either use a constructor as suggested, or, if at some point you have multiple constructors, you may wish to move the code that is common to them to an initializer:

```
public class GameRules {
final deck myDeckOfCards = new deck();

// instance initalizer
{
  myDeckOfCards.shuffle(); // no more error
}
```

But, as pointed out in the comments, using a constructor is better, chaining constructors if necessary. It turns out that instance initializers are best used in anonymous classes.

Comment: This isn't a wise idea.  If you have multiple constructors sharing the same code its always better to do constructor chaining instead of an instance initializer.  <http://leepoint.net/notes-java/oop/constructors/q-fi-constructor-chaining.html>

Comment: What's the downvote for? Is there is something wrong with using an instance initializer?

Comment: @Weegee, constructor chaining is nice too, but I don't see anything wrong with instance initializers either.

Comment: In general it is bad practice.  You are not able to deal with exceptions as well, and as Weegee points out, if you want to run code in multiple constructors, you should use constructor chaining.

Comment: (I did remove my downvote (and replaced it with an upvote) though.  The answer isn't wrong, I just don't think it's the best.)

Comment: @Justin, I agree, I should have posted is a comment to some other answer, as it merely suggests a worse alternative.

Comment: I replaced my downvote with an upvote as well given the revision.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you call `shuffle` method in `deck` constructor directly?